# script seem not load with use wp_enqueue_script

Tags: plugin-development

**edit : I unlocked using the rest api and not ajax (so no js) thanks to the response of Tom J Nowell**

*I'm pretty new in wordpress plugin dev*

I want to load some js for a plugin with ajax request.

To do so I have created the following code (I have removed the non necessary code) :

all the file is in the same folder into plugins

script.js

```js
console.log('loaded');
var ajax_url = wcdouchette_ajax_object.ajax_url;
console.log('ajax_url');
```

wc-douchette.php

```php
class Wcdouchette {
    protected function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }

    public function wcdouchette_includes() {
      // JavaScript
      wp_enqueue_script('wcdouchette-script-js', plugins_url( 'script.js', __FILE__ ));
      // Pass ajax_url to script.js
      wp_localize_script(
        'wcdouchette-script-js',
        'wcdouchette_ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
      );
    }

    private function init() {
      if (get_site_url() === 'https://wp-pp.test') $this->_isdev = true;
      add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'wcdouchette_includes'));
      add_action('wp_ajax_wcdouchette_send_to_pmp', array(&$this, 'wcdouchette_send_to_pmp'));
      add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end', array(&$this, 'wcdouchette_btn_in_wcactions_column'));
      add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'wcdouchette_options_page'));
      add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'wcdouchette_register_settings'));
    }
}
```

But i doesn't see any console.log. Any idea ?

Comment: `&$this` is a php 4.0 thing, WordPress hasn't supported PHP 4 for more than 10 years, you should replace it with `$this`. I also see you have a class that does several things, but you have not created an object of that class type or used it in the code you shared, can you share where you are using/creating/constructing the class in your question? Like functions, It's not enough to define a class, you have to use it, e.g. `$foo = new Bar();`

Comment: I would also note the filters suggest you're using the old `admin-ajax.php` API for AJAX, not the new REST API. `admin-ajax.php` handlers are difficult to debug and old, and don't have pretty URLs or human readable error messages

Comment: Did you look inside `window.url_object.ajax_url` ?